# Neo4j plugin works slowly

Tags: java, neo4j

I have a problem with my plugin. Firstly, I tried work with my database of 150K elements from my app using `RestGraphDatabase` for connection. Implementation  takes about 3s. Then I built `jar` and put it in folder "plugins". So now I can use my procedures from plugin, but they work much slower (about 17s). Can I speed up my plugin and how I can do it?

Procedures looks like that:

```
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Description;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Name;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure;

public class MyTraverser{

@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;

@Procedure(value = "path")
@Description("createPath")
public void createPath(@Name("startPoint") String startPoint, @Name("endPoint") String endPoint) {

    try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
        TraversalDescription td = db.traversalDescription().depthFirst()
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NODE_PATH)
                .relationships(RelationshipTypes.rel, Direction.BOTH)
                .evaluator(Evaluators.includingDepths(0, 10));

        Traverser tr = td
                .evaluator(Evaluators.includeWhereEndNodeIs(endPoint)
                .traverse(startPoint);

        tx.success();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm rather confused how this is compiling at all. `Evaluators.includeWhereEndNodeIs()` takes a series of Node parameters, and `traverse()` also takes Nodes (or a Node). They shouldn't compile when you're passing in Strings.

Comment: It works but very slow. This procedure finds all paths between two nodes. @ InverseFalcon

Comment: What version of Neo4j is this, and what are some example inputs for start and end points?

Comment: I use 3.3.2 version and endpoints are two nodes with different id